# Symfony 1.4 Admin Generator help on querybuilder()

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I've generated my admin module using Symfony generate-admin command, but I have a column which is a self-referencing ID ( which is a "parent" ID).

I want to display the matching "name" for that ID instead of the plain ID in the column.

Somehow I've come to the conclusion that I need to do a LEFT JOIN with the same same table in the queryBuilder() function of the action.class of my admin module, but I'm failing at it.

Let say I want this:

```
SELECT a.name, b.name FROM table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.parentId = b.id
```

I now how to do this in "plain" but not with Doctrine, how should I proceed?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using query builder then you should do something like:

```
$query->leftJoin('a.table2');
```

The `table2` is the name of the relation which should be defined in your schema.yml.